# How to get converter for DataGridColumn

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I need to get the converter for the DataGridColumn.
Here is DataGrid and Column 'NoteType' XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grdConsolidatedNotes"
          Grid.Row="3"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          BorderBrush="Transparent"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          ColumnWidth="*"
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ConsolidatedNotes}"
          LostFocus="GrdConsolidatedNotes_OnLostFocus"
          Padding="0"
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          SelectionUnit="FullRow"

          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          Visibility="{Binding Path=DataGridVisibility,
                               Mode=OneWay}"
          Sorting="GrdConsolidatedNotes_OnSorting">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto"
                                CellTemplate="{StaticResource CNNoteTypeCellTemplate}"
                                Header="{Binding hdrType,
                                                 Source={StaticResource ResourceString}}"
                                SortMemberPath="NoteType" />
```

Here is XAML for the CellTemplate 'CNNoteTypeCellTemplate' used above:

```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="CNNoteTypeCellTemplate">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="8" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="8" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="8" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="8" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock x:Name="NoteTypeTextBlock"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       MinHeight="20"
                       Margin="0,5,5,0"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="{Binding Path=NoteType,
                                      Converter={StaticResource noteTypeTextConverter}}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I need to retrieve the converter "noteTypeTextConverter" used above in code-behind.
Please suggest.

Comment: What do you mean by _retrieve_? This should already be defined in code-behind. If you have to write it, check [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx#data_conversion) (Data Conversion Section).

Comment: Can you explain why do you need to 'retrieve' the converter in code behind and in what event you want to retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

try this.FindResource("noteTypeTextConverter"); 
where this is where your noteTypeTextConverter is added.